# use saved Color in DB as Label forecolor

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, colors

I currently save color.value.name to sql db as string by following code

```
this.colorDialog1.Color.Name
```

but when I read the saved color from db and want to use as a fore color of Label by following code

```
this.label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(dbsavedcolorstring);
```

it doesnt work !!!

sometimes the saved color name in db is like "ffc8dd7d" but sometimes it saved as "Red" !? I don't know why ???

Comment: actually it works when it saved as "Red" but does not work when saved like "ffc8dd7d"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a synchronisation problem with the naming conventions. The `FromName Method` is meant for the names in the `System.Drawing.Color struct`; the ones you get, for example, when you type the following:

```
this.label3.ForeColor = Color.Red; //Red is the name expected in Color.FromName
```

But`colorDialog1.Color.Name` is not stored as `System.Drawing.Color` (mainly because the number of colors in this structure is much more limited than the potential options). You can force the `Color` to be stored as you wish (and rely on this convention when applying the color to the `Label`). For example:

```
Int storeAsARGB = this.colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb();
this.label3.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(storeAsARGB);
```